# where is stored information about custom rate table in pwa database?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ms-project

I'm working in SharePoint development field,
I work on a project that is about get resources information from project web app database.

I have following questions:

1. Where is stored information about custom rate table for each
   resource in pwa database?
2. Where is stored information about Each resource which uses custom rates per assignment? (MSP for each resource per assignment uses a custom rate...)

I found this code, it uses from psi [Resource web service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvcresource_di_pj14mref.aspx) to get answer of question 1:

```
    //Intialize webservice parameters
    Resource asvcResource = new Resource();
    asvcResource.Url = PROJECT_SERVER_URI + RESOURCE_SERVICE_PATH;
    NetworkCredential MyCredential = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password, Domain);
    asvcResource.Credentials = MyCredential;
   ResourceDataSet list_resources = asvcResource.ReadResources("", false);
```

Any help would be appreciated! Another suggestions would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick for this question
i select all column with name CostRateTable In My ProjectWepApp DataBase by using this query :

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
       NUMERIC_PRECISION, DATETIME_PRECISION, 
       IS_NULLABLE 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME='%costratetable%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='[your table schema]'
```

it's easy... enjoy it!